# np.where error when trying to select two columns

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, regression, valueerror

I am trying to perform a multiple regression on the 'Linnerud' dataset from sklearn.
I have an np array that is 20x3, but I only want to select two of the three columns.
I can add a single independent variable using:

```
X_for_1D_LR = X[:,np.where(np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Situps')[0]]
```

But am having issues trying to add another independent variable.

```
X_for_2D_LR = X[:,np.where(np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Situps', np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Chins')[0]]
```

and getting the error "ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given"
Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You are giving `where` two arguments.  It has two modes, one is alias for `np.nonzero` which takes just one argument.  The other `where` expects 3 arguments.  Did you spend any time (re)reading the `np.where` docs?  That should be the first stop when trying to debug errors like this.

Answer (score 0):

Restructure your code to make the logic more obvious. Python is a language that is generous with whitespace; use this to your advantage:

```
X_for_2D_LR = X[:,
                np.where(
                    np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Situps',
                    np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Chins'
                )[0]]
```

Perhaps now you can see your mistake if you read the error message `ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given` and the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for `np.where`.

Your conditionals (eg. `np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Situps'`) are in a list and should be separated by boolean operators, not a commas:

```
X_for_2D_LR = X[:,
                np.where(
                    np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Situps' or
                    np.array([feature_names_X])[0] == 'Chins'
                )[0]]
```